# Sufficient conditions for an entire function to be constant or polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Can you provide different sufficient conditions (with justification) for an entire function ($f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C},$ $f$ is analytic functions on $\mathbb{C}$) to be a polynomial or constant function.

For example,

Boundedness is a condition for $f$ to be constant.

Or, having pole at infinity is a sufficient condition for $f$ to be a polynomial.

Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: See  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial We can just consider the real part of the entire function.

Comment: The existence of a point $z_0$ such that $f^{(n)}(z_0)=0$ for all but finitely many $n$ is a sufficient (and necessary) condition.

Answer (score 2):

If there exist a nonnegative integer $n$ and constant $M$ such that $$|f(z)| \le M|z|^n$$
for all $z\in \Bbb C$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

The proof is similar to showing that bounded entire functions are constant. Cauchy's estimate tells us that
$$|f^{(n+1)}(0)| \le \sup_{|z| \le R}\dfrac{(n+1)!|f(z)|}{R^{n+1}} \le M(n+1)!\dfrac{1}{R}$$
for all $R > 0$. Letting $R\to\infty$ tells us that $f^{(n+1)}(0) = 0$.

A similar application shows that $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for all $k > n$ and thus, the power series at $0$ reduces to just the first $n$ terms. Since the function is entire, the function equals this power series everywhere.

---

The above is a necessary condition if we modify it to be:
If $f$ is a polynomial, then there exists a nonnegative integer $n$ and constants $M, R > 0$ such that
$$|f(z)| \le M|z|^n$$
for all $z$ satisfying $|z| > R$.

Comment: (To be a necessary condition, it must be modified to something like $|f(z)| \le M(1+|z|)^n$, otherwise it typically fails near $z=0$.)

Comment: @GregMartin: Oh yes, that was quite clumsy of me. Thank you. Have fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

An entire function is a nonconstant polynomial if and only if it is proper (in other words if $K$ compact and $f^{-1}(K)=L$ then $L$ is compact)

Proof: exercise for the OP with the following hints:

A non constant polynomial satisfies $|f(z)| \to \infty, |z| \to \infty$ (why?)
Show that this implies $f$ proper (use contradiction and the fact that compact is equivalent to closed and bounded in the plane)

Conversely, show that $f$ entire proper implies  $|f(z)| \to \infty, |z| \to \infty$ (see hint above)

Conclude that $f$ is polynomial - one can do it using machinery like the density of image near essential singularities, but also one can simply consider $g(z)=1/f(1/z)$ which is holomorphic near zero and has a removable singularity at zero with value zero.

If $k \ge 1$ is the order of the zero of $g$ there, show that it then follows that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ by showing that $f(z)/z^k \to c \ne 0, \infty, |z| \to \infty$

Comment: Please justify your answer properly. Language is quite clumsy to understand.

Comment: what about you do it as an exercise following the hints I've given? I've rewritten it so it's clearer but per mathstackechange guidelines, it is highly encouraged for the OP to do some work too

Answer (score 0):

If for some finite $M$, an entire function$f$ satisfies $\mathrm{lim}_{z\rightarrow\infty}|f(z)|=M$ then $f$ is constant.

If $\mathrm{lim}_{z\rightarrow\infty}|f(z)|=M$ then $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $\infty$. That is, there is $R>0$ such that $f$ is bounded in $\{z\in\Bbb{C}:|z|>R\}$. And since $\{z\in\Bbb{C}:|z|\leq R\}$ is compact, so $f$ is bounded on it also. Hence $f$ is a bounded entire function.